# ssis timeout when running Execute sql task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, execute-sql-task

how to hand handled ssis timeout when running Execute sql task.
in execute sql task ,I am calling the stored procedure
connectiong type is oledb connection
TImeout  is 0 (infinity)

I am getting the following error when I try to  run in BIDS.

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Exec
>   [test].[user_empinfor_sp]" failed with the following error: "Query
>   timeout expired". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

please tell me how to avoid timout expire time in ssis  package side and what steps we need to follow to avoid this error in ssis package.

Comment: You need to change _command_ timeout rather than connection timeout

Comment: Try changing both Connection Timeout and Command Timeout. Also, figure out which chunk is causing the timeout in your stored procedure. Break down your stored procedures into 4 or 5 chunks and try executing one by one and check where exactly timeout is happening.